# Pivot point trouble

Tags: modeling, import

I'm new in Blender. I imported an FBX file with 4 objects.

Apparently, the pivot point was external to the object, so I changed it and now it's inside the object, such as I wanted. The problem is that after this, a dashed line appears to the old pivot point and when I try to move the object, somehow the object is connected with that point.

Can you tell me what the problem is?

[image: object, external point and dashed line]

[image: When I move the object you can see that the dashed line "follows me"]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi Duarte, thank you for your help. I've just uploaded the file.

Comment: Please share the URL